# Android parse JSON with multiple array response from php

Tags: android, json

I recently started working with andorid.

How to parse dynamic json with multiple arrays response from php server.

**Login Response**

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": {
        "msg": "LoggedIn",
        "user_id": "2"
    }
}
```

**Login response with error message**

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "data": "No users found with given email."
}
```

and an other one

Inventory List

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "inventory_id": "33",
            "apron_id": "123456",
            "nickname": "uyi",
            "location": "13",
            "manufacture": "0",
            "garment_type": "yuyh",
            "color": "juki",
            "core_material": "ytyt",
            "Date_purchase": "2015-04-10",
            "UID_no": "ikujki",
            "serial": "iui",
            "Batch": "ikk",
            "Expiration": "2015-04-23",
            "QTY": "898",
            "apron_status": "0",
            "apron_retire": "0",
            "created_user": "2",
            "created_time": "2015-04-10 05:22:38",
            "update_time": "2015-04-10 05:22:38"
        },
        {
            "inventory_id": "32",
            "apron_id": "12345mn",
            "nickname": "gfhgh",
            "location": "12",
            "manufacture": "0",
            "garment_type": "hgjyhj",
            "color": "ytgtfghtg",
            "core_material": "fhgfhy",
            "Date_purchase": "2015-04-28",
            "UID_no": "rtryttttttttt",
            "serial": "hfh",
            "Batch": "rtrrtyy",
            "Expiration": "2015-03-17",
            "QTY": "7688",
            "apron_status": "0",
            "apron_retire": "0",
            "created_user": "2",
            "created_time": "2015-04-10 05:15:54",
            "update_time": "2015-04-10 05:15:54"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: yes tutorial is clear thank you @MdAbdulGafur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get login response you can do like this

```
JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(result.toString());

String status=jobj.getString("status");

if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
{
    //login success

   JSONObject Jdata=jobj.getJSONObject("data");

   String Message=Jdata.getString("msg");
   String UserId=Jdata.getString("user_id");
}
else
{
    //failure
}
```

and for Inventory List you can do like this

```
JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(result.toString());

JSONArray arrData=jobj.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i = 0; i < arrData.length(); i++)
{

        JSONObject jdata=arrData.getJSONObject(i);

        //here u can get all field like this

        String  nickname=jdata.getString("nickname");
}
```

Comment: data in login Json not always array it will be error text also says "Invalid Login Details" @Dhaiyur

Comment: @manikantag post that response

Comment: One more is i'm storing user_id with storeRegistrationId(context,UserId) how long this user_id will be remain @Dhaiyur

Comment: what id storeRegistrationId?? Is this Sheredpreference??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76055/discussion-between-dhaiyur-and-manikanta-g).

Comment: ok i got it i have to use shared preferences to maintain sessions in android  right?? @Dhaiyur

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) classes.

You can parse extremely simply:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
int status = json.getInt("status");
```

Using both an Array and an Object for your "data" key will make things irritating for you. You should think about using a different key, or another key that will dictate to you what you are reading.

Comment: data in login Json not always array it will be error text also says "Invalid Login Details" @Knossos